# Filling in the predefined Word Document Template from SharePoint Site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio, custom-list, word

I have a requirement which asks for filling the details into a word doc with a predefined template from SharePoint site and then the word doc should be automatically saved when clicked on saved button.

1. Need to understand whether can fill in a predefined word template from Sharepoint site
2. Can it be acheieved from list or library , say filling the list details and save after finish should reflect in word doc with a predefined template
3. I want that filled doc to be saved in SharePoint site itself.
4. All the above steps possible,if so what tools should I use

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Thanks 
T Kartheek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very possible using the following:

- A Document Content Type holding all the fields you want to have appear in your document
- A Template library that holds your document template and is using the
  above content type
- A second document library that will have the above content type and has the
  template document above as its document template (advanced
  settings under Document Library Settings - Content Type Name)
- A custom list that has the same fields as those used in your content type.
- A SharePoint Designer workflow that will run on the creation of an
  item in your custom list above.

Once you upload your template to the template library, open the template from SharePoint and in Word (assuming 2013 but could be 2010 also) and go to Insert -> QuickParts -> Document Property. You should see the other content type fields appear here. Add them to the document and save it back to SharePoint when ready.

In the second document library add the same content type and make sure that it's template refers to the template document you uploaded above.

In SharePoint designer, create a workflow that will run against the custom list you will create. The workflow only needs to do one thing, create a new item in the secondary library above.

In the workflow action, make sure you specify the correct content type, and you map the fields from your custom list to the related content type fields. Ensure the workflow will run on the creation of an item.

Then whenever a user adds an item to your custom list, the workflow will fire and create a new document in your secondary document library. It will also copy the custom item values that the user entered to the secondary document library.

When a user opens the new document it will pull those values in as per your template.

I hope this helps, I know it is a bit convoluted but I wanted to show you how you can do this more or less out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just just a document set.. The Properties on a Document will synchronize to the properties of all the documents in the document set. When you bind a content control in the document to the properties on the document set -- there is a  Content Synchronization job that runs against all the document sets to re-sync the properties on the document set onto the documents in the library.. Then the content types will automatically pick up the values of the document properties (fields don't automatically resync).. All done - no workflow. Should take about 10 minutes to setup... You can select which properties on the document set participate in the resynch...